# Creating an Erdos-Renyi grah in Julia and obtaining the adjacency matrix

Tags: julia

I would like to generate an Erdos-Renyi random graph with julia and most importantly get the adjacency matrix. I have tried the following code:

```
using Erdos
using PyPlot
g = erdos_renyi(100, 0.1);
am = adjacency_matrix(g);
imshow(am)
```

However, the plot I get for the adjacency matrix does not seem right.
[image]

How can I generate them properly? Even if its with a different Julia package.

Comment: try `imshow(am)`; I use `LightGraphs` not `Euler` but this should be equivalent; in fact it is strange that `imshow(g)` works (it does not under `LightGraphs`)

Comment: Sorry, I made I typo when posting. The plot was produced with imshow(am).  The problem seems to be on the Erdos package, since it also worked for me with LightGraphs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with LightGraphs package:

```
using LightGraphs
using PyPlot

G = erdos_renyi(100, .1)
A = adjacency_matrix(G) # A is a sparse matrix

# convert to dense matrix before plotting
imshow(full(A))
```

[image]

Comment: As I have noted above - `imshow` accepts sparse matrix so `imshow(A)` is enough.

Comment: Even better than `imshow` for sparse matrices is `spy`